# Best resources For learning JSP and Servlets?

Tags: jsp, servlets

what are all the best online resources for learning JSP and servlets from scratch?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482639/which-is-the-best-book-for-learning-java-servlets-and-jsp

Comment: first of all google it then add here

Comment: Point your mouse over the `jsp` and `servlets` tags, wait for the popbox and click `info` link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Baldwin has some excellent Java tutorials at http://www.dickbaldwin.com/toc.htm, and there are servlet and JSP tutorials on his Advanced Java page at http://www.dickbaldwin.com/tocadv.htm.